# RewriteMap not working for urls with query params

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewritemap

It seems rewritemap is not considering query params in matching url. Please suggest a solution.

My setup in httpd.conf file:

```
RewriteMap redirects dbm=db:/usr/local/apache/conf/redirects.db
RewriteCond ${redirects:$1} !=""
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${redirects:$1} [redirect=permanent,last]
```

redirects file has urls lile

```
/same_url/ http://mysite.com/
/same_url/?q=1 http://mysite.com/q2=1
/same_url/?q=2 http://mysite.com/q2=2
/same_url/?q=3 http://mysite.com/q2=3
```

But all 4 urls are getting directed to http://mysite.com only. So it seems matching is only done against non-query part.

Please help.

Comment: it looks like apache does not consider query param in 'RewriteRule'.

Comment: Query strings are removed when matching with RewriteRule. You should look at `%{QUERY_STRING}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your RewriteMap it seems that you do not need to use a map.
You can do it without a map:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q\=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^/same_url/(.*)$ http://example.com/q2=%1 [redirect=permanent,last]
```

Pay attention to the `%1` in the RewriteRule backreferencing to the match in the RewriteCond.

If you still want to use a Rewrite map you might have to "transform" the query string into something in the path
The rules could be:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q\=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /$1/q=%1   <-- here the GET param is transformed to something in the path

RewriteMap redirects dbm=db:/usr/local/apache/conf/redirects.db
RewriteCond ${redirects:$1} !=""
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${redirects:$1} [redirect=permanent,last]
```

You'll have to change your map to something not considering GET params:

```
/same_url/ http://example.com/
/same_url/q=1 http://example.com/q2=1
/same_url/q=2 http://example.com/q2=2
/same_url/q=3 http://example.com/q2=3
```